# Parameter 0 of constructor in my class required a bean of my second class that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

I know it's a problem that is been posted 100 times, but unfortunately I am getting a `Defining Bean` error in my `Spring Boot` Application and I really do not know why. I do not see my error from launch to finish since I am defining a bean.

I would appreciate any help.

I'm sure it's a stupid mistake which I just don't see

My error Code

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.jwt.JwtSecretKey required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.jwt.JwtConfig' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.jwt.JwtConfig' in your configuration.
```

JwtSecretKey class

```
package com.example.demo.jwt;

import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

@Configuration
public class JwtSecretKey {

  private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;

  @Autowired
  public JwtSecretKey(JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
    this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
  }

  @Bean
  public SecretKey secretKey() {
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(jwtConfig.getSecretKey().getBytes());
  }
}
```

JwtConfig class

```
package com.example.demo.jwt;

import com.google.common.net.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.jwt")
public class JwtConfig {

  private String secretKey;
  private String tokenPrefix;
  private Integer tokenExpirationAfterDays;

  public JwtConfig() {}

  public String getSecretKey() {
    return secretKey;
  }

  public void setSecretKey(String secretKey) {
    this.secretKey = secretKey;
  }

  public String getTokenPrefix() {
    return tokenPrefix;
  }

  public void setTokenPrefix(String tokenPrefix) {
    this.tokenPrefix = tokenPrefix;
  }

  public Integer getTokenExpirationAfterDays() {
    return tokenExpirationAfterDays;
  }

  public void setTokenExpirationAfterDays(Integer tokenExpirationAfterDays) {
    this.tokenExpirationAfterDays = tokenExpirationAfterDays;
  }
```

Comment: what is the spring boot version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your `JwtConfig` class with `@Configuration`

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.jwt")
public class JwtConfig {
```

See in Javadocs:

> Annotation for externalized configuration. Add this to a class
> definition or a @Bean method in a @Configuration class if you want to
> bind and validate some external Properties (e.g. from a .properties
> file).

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html